# Laptop goes into hibernate when it is suspended (only happens on Wednesdays)

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

Every night I put my laptop into suspend mode and disconnect it from power and network.  It seems that each Wednesday (it may not be every Wednesday but it is always on a  Wednesday) morning I find that I have to wake my laptop up from a hibernate.  I've looked in my Windows event logs and I see that there is some activity around 7AM (give or take a couple minutes).  Note that this is about two hours prior to my turning the laptop on.  I see an event from the Power-Troubleshooter source indicating that the that the wake source was a timer but it doesn't tell me which timer.  So I then look at the Task Scheduler and it says that no tasks have run in the past 24 hours.  I then try the command `powercfg -lastwake` but this is the output:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
  Wake Source Count - 0
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this seemingly scheduled task to cause a wake up at this time?  This is especially annoying because when my laptop is woken up with the lid closed Windows defaults to 1024x768 (or some other low resolution) and all of my windows are resized and moved to the upper left corner of the screen.

TL;DR - Laptop wakes itself up from suspend on Wednesday mornings and then puts itself into hibernate 2 minutes later for no apparent reason.

Comment: Is it the day after windows updates (once a month 2nd Tuesday) or every Wednesday?

Comment: Well, it's not quite every Wednesday but I also don't think it is windows update related since it happened this morning.

Comment: Guess not, it was the only thing I could think of that would wake your PC in the middle of a Tuesday night.

Comment: I konw, that was the first thing that I was thinking of when I first saw this but this has been happening for a couple months now and it has occurred more than a couple times...

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS hasn't got a wake time set, it's pretty unlikely but worth a look.

Comment: Windows Update will update Defender much more frequently than Patch Tuesday, so it still could be Windows Update causing this.  Try disabling automatic updates for awhile to see if it continues.

Comment: @Col - Interesting, I'll take a next my next reboot.

Comment: @gordoco - I just realized I had disabled windows updates a few months ago when I first suspected that it was causing this.

Comment: @jason, do you still have the problem?

Comment: @mic84, yes it happened again this Wednesday morning.  And that was with your suggestion to disable 'allow wake up timers'.  Sure enough in my event viewer I see a wake up event at 6:52 this morning with "Wake Source: Timer - ".  This is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I've resolved this.  I ended up updating my video card driver and so far I'm not seeing the issue anymore (I really can't explain why the driver would somehow behave on a weird schedule like this).  I had to go to Nvidia's web site to get the driver since I was using the latest version that Dell had available.

Answer (score 0):

What does your Reliability Monitor show for the last few months? Is anything happening, such as a new add-on to IE or SP1 update?

If you type the day/date into your Search Menu, you should get all that was changed on that/ those days. It shows in 'more search results'.

This will tell you in detail, settings, etc. It prints HTML to desktop and admin:

```
cd %userprofile%\Desktop  
powercfg -energ
```

1. Remote management unclicked in 'system props-remote'.
2. Disable wake by moving mouse, etc. (cleaners may move it when they do there job-if on that day\night or other employees who get to work earlier).
3. Disable 'allow wake up timers'

   In Control Panel:

   Power Options -> change power settings -> advanced power settings -> sleep -> disable 'allow wake up timers'.

   Also in Advanced Power Settings, check 'what bat. does when low' config to below 25% so Windows will show a warning. Above 15-20%, it may try to warn you, then lock down (hibernate) to protect or save.
4. Checking the BIOS as pointed out by @Col.
5. Remote chances if at all:

   When is defrag set to run/ or full security scan/, or is auto backup/ or check for updates (Google or system updates checks)?

Comment: I looked in the reliability history and didn't notice anything suspicious.  I think this has been doing this ever since I got it (it's a Dell laptop I got back in April, I think).  I don't quite follow all of your suggestions but I disabled the wake timers in advanced power settings, I'm hopeful that will fix the issue.  Oddly, powercfg -waketimers shows no timers.  Although, the event viewer suggests that a wake timer is what caused the behavior (but it doesn't tell me which timer, grr).

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling hibernate in the Power Options.  Perhaps whatever is causing it to hibernate will throw an error.

Comment: I don't think I want to do that as I do use hibernate sometimes (when I know I'm not going to have power for a while).  Also, I don't think it will solve the issue as I think it would still wake from sleep and then just go back to sleep instead of hibernate.

Comment: its not a permanent thing, its just a troubleshooting step.  By disabling it, hopefully you can pinpoint what is causing the error.  You can always re-enable it.